# Frame load interrupted error while loading a word document in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

I want to load a word document using UIWebView. I used the code provided in
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1630.html
to load the document.

But not all the documents load successfully. Sometimes I get an error

```
Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 UserInfo=0x145bc10 "Frame load interrupted"
```

The error seems to be very sporadic and I get this error only for some documents.
However the same document loads correctly in mail.app.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason was, the file I tried to load doesn't contain a extension.
I was purposely removing the file extension (.doc and .ppt) which I think confused the UIWebView. Seems like iPhone ignores the OS 9 legacy typecodes completely. :)

Comment: I found this answer googling my similar problem. This solution solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone fix the issue? I have similar problem,

Comment: This issue seems to have made a come back in iOS 7. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304311/not-able-to-load-the-filedoc-pdf-etc-from-url-in-uiwebview-for-ios-7

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a Radar regarding this issue. It's resolved in the latest version of iPhone OS 4.0.

http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=381401

Comment: Wow.., That's nice. Thanks for notifying me!

Comment: I guess a new Radar needs to be filled out, because this issue crops up when you have a different extension than one it is expecting, even in iOS 4.  I would expect that UIWebView would actually read the header of the file or something to determine what it is if it cannot determine its file type by extension.