# iPhone - NSError reference : constants and code

Tags: iphone, constants, nserror

I'm searching some precise doc where I can associate an error number to its constant. Let's say, for example, I'm searching the constant of NSError.code = 102. How may I do to find it ? Searching the Web does not help. Searching the headers file is a headache.

How would you do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find some of refrences here for NSError

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html

you can found some of error detail here

http://www.lifeasbob.com/Code/ErrorCodes.aspx

Comment: did you just found my 102 example error before answering ? I don't find it. Please update your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The code should belong to the domain of `NSError`, check the documentation for the associated error domain and you should find the correct code. The domain is also a good hint of which headers to search if documentation is unavailable. Apple does list the [Foundation Constants](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: That's what I've done. Did you just found my 102 example error in the link you give ? I've searched there and I don't find it. Please update your answer.

Comment: Please post the Error domain, so if your error code is 102 what is the string returned from `[yourError domain]`? And also what library are you using.

Comment: I don't know. I just know I have to check the 102 error and I'd like to know what kind of error it is not to copy/paste sample code. And I have to do this for other error codes. And also, instead of testing 102, I want to test the corresponding constant, so I'd like to find it.

Comment: That is why I am telling you to post the error domain. If you have an NSError then do this `NSLog("%@", [error domain]); and post the name of the domain it is printing.

Answer (score 0):

It's WebKitErrorDomain - WebKitErrorFrameLoadInterruptedByPolicyChange

[Frame load interrupted error while loading a word document in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482736/frame-load-interrupted-error-while-loading-a-word-document-in-uiwebview)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Miscellaneous/WebKit_Constants/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/WebKit_Policy_Errors